# My WiFi connection keeps getting dropped, and then requiring password, over and over again

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager

I spent time searching for solutions to this issue, and none seemed to be particularly helpful in my scenario. Periodically, what will happen is when I'm using my primary network, my connection will drop, and I'll be asked for my WiFi password. I'll give it the password, and it may reconnect, but more likely, it'll just ask me for the password... over, and over, and over again.

I have three networks available to me, two of which are 2.4GHz and 5GHz variants of the same one, meaning there are technically two that I have access to - my primary network, and the network that has 2.4GHz and 5GHz variants. I've noticed that the issue doesn't seem to occur on the 2.4GHz variant (though I haven't used the 2.4GHz network long enough to be certain). I have verified that the settings "All users can connect" and "All users can access the password (unencrypted)" are enabled. The issue can happen within minutes of a fresh boot.

Not being an advanced Linux user has made following through other users' posts and solutions difficult for me. It often seems that other users posting solutions expect the original poster to already know most of what's going on, when that may not be the case. This is why I'm asking here.

My computer is running Ubuntu 20.04 (not the beta, the full release), using both the standard Ubuntu desktop, as well as KDE Plasma. The issue occurs in both desktop environments. My WiFi adapter is an MSI AC905C, which has an Intel chipset (though I can't be certain which particular one it is). Does anyone have any suggestions for me?

```
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone Peak] [8086:24fb] (rev 10)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone Peak] [8086:2110]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: Added output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` to the main post.

Comment: What kind of Access Point do you have?

Answer (score 1):

I would try these two things.

1. Forget the connection. And then disable the wallet system. That is the Plasma version but I think that Ubuntu has something similar. Then reconnect and try again.
2. Second thing is search for other drivers for your WiFi hardware.  In Plasma it is in System Settings under Driver manager.

Comment: The currently installed driver is `backport-iwlwifi-dkms - distro free` for a Stone Peak Intel 3168NGW chipset. The KDE Driver Manager was not showing me my currently installed drivers (as it kept getting stuck on "collecting system information"). It did show me the drivers briefly, though. I checked using `ubuntu-drivers devices` in the terminal.

Comment: I also disconnected from the network and reconnected, and so far it's fine, but it's a very sporadic issue, so I'm not sure it's good yet.

Comment: Nope, happened again.

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do to solve this issue was to unplug my network router for a couple minutes and plug it back in to reboot it. The issue has not occurred since, even over 24 hours later. I can't believe I hadn't thought to try that before, since it's the easiest solution.

I have since reinstalled Ubuntu 20.04 (due to issues unrelated to this) and my network has not dropped yet. I'm glad I did, because I managed to restore about 600GB of storage across both my drives, even with all the same games and applications I had installed as before.